# iphone site display issue

Tags: css, viewport

My site is not displaying correctly on iphone5 and 4s.

The url is: http://www.mya.co.uk/nonsurgicaldev/index.html

The content does not fit the screen width when the phone is in portrait view and in both landscape and portrait view there is a large margin on the left hand side and none on the right.

I have a form on the page and had hidden the original checkboxes like this:

```
:root input[type=checkbox] {
position: absolute;
left: -6em;
}
```

and I thought it might have something to do with this, but I removed the checkbox replacement css and I still have the problem.

I have included:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
<script>
if (screen.width > 740) {
var mvp = document.getElementById('testViewport');
mvp.setAttribute('content','width=740');
}
</script>
```

in my head tags.

Can anybody help me with this issue please? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS, it is quite widely documented and you can solve it by using the `<meta>` tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">`

Or by using a javascript solution as found in this [Webdsigner wall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug) article.